# Scripts on mac. Auto execute from USB?

Tags: macos, command-line

I have written a simple script for macbook and later found a program called platypus which makes an .sh file to an .app

Now I want to ask if it's possible to launch that app from the USB automatically as soon as it's plugged in?

And if somehow yes. Does it also work if the mac is closed or just in login Screen?

Comment: That would be a pretty major security bug if something like this worked without explicit user permission.

Comment: yeah thought so, i wanted to know cause my macbook have really many photos and i move them around quite often. so if it was possibly?

Comment: great thx a bunch

Comment: (BTW, one of the first Google hits would be http://www.lightroomfanatic.com/tutorials/advanced/how-to-automatically-launch-lightroom-by-inserting-a-media-card/ -- which looks straightforward enough to adapt for non-Lightroom uses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this wont work. This is one of the advantages of macOS, it does not execute stuff that is found on a USB drive.

I consider this a great deal when we talk about security.

However there are devices that look like an USB thumb drive, but when plugged in expose themselves as a HID (Human Interface Device) and then execute keyboard shortcuts to run their exploits.

For example the [USB Rubber Ducky Deluxe](https://hakshop.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe) is such a device.

Comment: Other operating systems also do not execute stuff that is found on a flash drive (unless configured to do so).